# Is this a placeholder link or not?

Tags: html

HTML5 [specifies](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html) `<a>` elements without an href as "placeholder links". A decent explanation of some placeholder link use-cases is [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tutorials/qt/html5-placeholder-links.htm).  A contentious discussion during definition of the HTML5 spec is [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2007Jun/0661.html).  But nowhere is there a precise definition of what is or isn't a placeholder link.

Anyway, we're trying to figure out whether text that is not clickable should be a placeholder link (using `<a>`) or just a regular `<span>`.

We have a web app with a list like this:

- 12/10/2014   [Invoice #123](http://#)
- 12/18/2014   [Invoice #456](http://#)
- 01/19/2014   No Invoice
- 01/19/2014   Multiple Invoices

The first two items in the list are hyperlinks with valid URLs. The latter two are not clickable. The first because there's no invoice. The second in theory could have been clickable, but it's a rare use-case that our team chose not to write code to support, so we just show static text instead of making it a link.

Because of the way that this list is populated in code, it would be technically simpler for us to make all these `<a>` elements and simply omit the href attribute from the latter two. But is this the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're use case doesn't really match. The intent of placeholder links is that they serve as a *placeholder* for where a link might be. For example, as you move from link to link, links to the current page might become a placeholder. The items you're showing have no notion of linking at all, so it seems like semantic abuse of the anchor tag.

Also, I wouldn't mess with unclear specs unless you're in for a world of pain, especially if you ever need to support anything legacy. Browsers are notoriously evil.